# How to diable slack url previews in golang

Tags: go, url, slack, slack-api

I want to send a message with a website link to slack through slack bot. Slack by defaults create the preview for that link. I wan't to disable the preview.

Here is my code:

```
s := slack.New("Bot-Token", slack.OptionDebug(true))

    data := `TEST: Slack link Preview 101 
     <https://www.google.com/maps|publish>`

    params := slack.PostMessageParameters{
        UnfurlLinks: false,
        UnfurlMedia: false,
    }

    _, t, err := s.PostMessage(
        "ChannelID",
        slack.MsgOptionText(data, false),
        slack.MsgOptionPostMessageParameters(params),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err.Error())
    }
```

[Its displaying the message as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PsKt.png)

[But I want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcOxe.png)